# Getting banned while web scraping with tor - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am web scraping a website using Selenium and I was getting my IP banned when quitting and reopening the browser (I had to quit my browser because the search is very long, hence if I wouldn't do that I would get a lot of slowdowns).

So I decided to make some changes and use a tor webdriver instead of a Mozilla one. I thought that by doing that I would not be recognized by that website because once you quit and reopen Tor you get a different IP. However, I am still getting the MaxRetryError...

Can you help me understand why and possibly find some workarounds? Thanks.

Comment: What should we answer? You did not give any technical details and frankly speaking why you are getting blocked is not a programming issue.

Comment: I wanted to understand how that was possible. How can that website still recognize me even once I changed my IP address? If you want I can edit my question sharing a bit of code and how I am accessing the tor webdriver

Comment: The core topic of this website is fixing errors in code and algorithms. How websites recognize malicious behaviour is not related to that.